# Why array is not iterable in reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I want to split array by even and odd elements, this is my code

```
A.reduce((a,v,i)=> v % 2 == 0 ? [...a[0],v] : [...a[1],v],[[],[]])
```

`A` is array of numbers. I don't understand why do I get an error

> a[1] is not iterable?

Considering that this code is working ok:

```js
let arr = [[],[]];
console.log([...arr[1], 4]);
```

Comment: What does the `A` array look like?

Comment: @VasilDininski, I added in the post

Comment: `arr.reduce...` works fine, with your reduce function and arr definition. Seems most likely you've defined `A` as a 1d array.

Comment: Once you've been through one iteration, you've spread the original `a[0]` or `a[1]` into the result array, so the accumulator is no longer a 2D array.

Comment: On a side note, do you believe this one liner is readable? :)

Comment: Array "A" should be a string/object/array or any iterable. I think your components at the array are not iterables. Review your array instance.

Comment: @Icepickle, I was just playing on leetcode, not for production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only returning a single array in `reduce()`. You also need to return the second.
In the first iteration the `a` is `[[],[]]`. But after the first it will become only a single array.

```js
let A = [1,2,3,4]
const res= A.reduce((a,v,i)=> v % 2 == 0 ? [a[0],[...a[1],v]] : [[...a[0],v],a[1]],[[],[]])
console.log(res)
```

You could use a trick here. As `v % 2` will return `1` or `0` so you could `push()` to that and use `,` to return the original `a` without spread operator.

```js
let A = [1,2,3,4]
const res= A.reduce((a,v,i)=> (a[v % 2].push(v),a),[[],[]])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment to make this a little easier -

```js
const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

const result =
  data.reduce
    ( ([ odd, even ], v) =>
        Boolean (v & 1)
          ? [ [...odd, v], even ]
          : [ odd, [...even, v] ]
    , [ [], [] ]
    )
    
console.log(result)
// [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
```

You can make a generic function, `partition` -

```js
const partition = (p, a = []) =>
  a.reduce
    ( ([ t, f ], v) =>
        p (v)
          ? [ [...t, v], f ]
          : [ t, [...f, v] ]
    , [ [], [] ]
    )


const evenOdds =
  partition (v => Boolean (v & 1), [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])

const lessThan2 =
  partition (v => v < 2, [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
    
console.log(evenOdds)
// [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]

console.log(lessThan2)
// [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```

Comment: ... um even based on the value not on the index right?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just filter twice:

```
  const res = [A.filter(it => it % 2), A.filter(it => !(it % 2))];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that in reduce function you return one array of many elements (not one array with two arrays). Try this instead (where B=[[],[]], time complexity **n** )

```
A.forEach(x=> B[x%2].push(x) )
```

```js
let A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], B=[ [],[] ];
A.forEach(x=> B[x%2].push(x) );

console.log(B);
```